# Metal - Threads and ThreadGroups

Tags: multithreading, metal

I am learning `Metal` right now and trying to understand the lines below:

```
let threadGroupCount = MTLSizeMake(8, 8, 1) ///line 1
let threadGroups = MTLSizeMake(drawable.texture.width / threadGroupCount.width, drawable.texture.height / threadGroupCount.height, 1) ///line 2

command_encoder.dispatchThreadgroups(threadGroups, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadGroupCount) ///line 3
```

1. for the `line 1`, What is the 3 integers represent? My guess is to assign the number of threads to be used in the process but which is which?
2. What is the different between `line 1` and 'line 2'? My guess again is the different between threads and thread groups. But I am not sure what is the fundamental difference and when to use what.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When dispatching a grid of work items to a compute kernel, it is your responsibility to divide up the grid into subsets called *threadgroups*, each of which has a total number of threads (width * height * depth) that is less than the `maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup` of the corresponding compute pipeline state.

The `threadsPerThreadgroup` size indicates the "shape" of each subset of the grid (i.e. the number of threads in each grid dimension). The `threadgroupsPerGrid` parameter indicates how many threadgroups make up the entire grid. As in your code, it is often the dimensions of a texture divided by the dimensions of your threadgroup size you've chosen.

One performance note: each compute pipeline state has a `threadExecutionWidth` value that indicates how many threads of a threadgroup will be scheduled and executed together by the GPU. The optimal threadgroup size will thus always be a multiple of `threadExecutionWidth`. During development, it's perfectly acceptable to just dispatch a small square grid as you're currently doing.

Answer (score 1):

The first line gives you the number of threads per group (in this case two-dimensional 8x8), while the second line gives you the number of groups per grid. Then the [dispatchThreadgroups(_:threadsPerThreadgroup:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/metal/mtlcomputecommandencoder/1443138-dispatchthreadgroups) function on the third line uses these two numbers. The number of groups can be omitted in which case it defaults to using one group.